# Python 3 - plotting a 3D graph with Axes3D.plot_wireframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have some trouble with plotting a 3D plot with matplotlib (Axes3D).

I have the following code that calls a function I defned called "solver"

```
    x_accuracy = 1 #Increase to get a more detailed plot ; DEFAULT = 1
    y_accuracy = 1
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    time = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
    Radiuses, Time = np.meshgrid(radiuses, time)
    #concentrations_norm = np.array([[solver(radiuses[i]*a, t, D, C_init, a)/C_init for i in range(len(radiuses))] for t in time])
    Concentrations_norm = solver(radiuses, time, D, C_init, a)
    ax.plot_wireframe(Radiuses, Time, Concentrations_norm, x_accuracy, y_accuracy)
    plt.show()
```

Here is the solver function :

```
def solver(r, t, D, C_init, a):
    """
    Function to solve the equation of diffusion for a cylinder of radius a.

    -------

    Arguments :
    r - radius at which we evaluate C (concentraion in particles)
    t - time at which we evaluate C (concentration in particles)
    D - diffusion coefficient
    C_init - initial concentration in particles
    a - initial radius of the cylinder(or sphere)

    --------

    Returns :

    C(r,t) - Concentration of particles at radius r, and instant t
    """
    integral, err = quad(function_to_integrate, 0, a, (r, t, D))
    return C_init/(2*D*t)*np.exp(-r**2/(4*D*t)) * integral
```

the function to integrate is super basic, here is the code below :

```
def function_to_integrate(rp, r, t, D):
    """
    Function used solely to be integrated using scipy.integrate.quad(). Used in solver function.

    --------

    Arguments :
    rp - integrate variable
    r - radius we evaluate the function at
    t - time we evaluate the function at
    D - diffusion coefficient

    ---------

    Returns :

    exp(-rp²/4Dt)I0(r*rp/2Dt)rp
    """

    return np.exp(-rp**2/(4*D*t))*np.i0([float(r*rp/(2*D*t))])*rp
```

When I try to plot that 3D graph, python yields : 
    TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

saying that occurs at the return of the solver function. I don't understand why I get this error and how to fix it.